# How to configure a published package as a website in IIS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis, msbuild, teamcity, publishing

I want to auto publish the sites using teamcity. I am using teamcity's Visual studio to publish a website. It creates a pre-compiled web directory as following

```
 D:\publish\PrecompiledWeb\Books in the checkout directory.
```

Now I need to use it with IIS. If I point the IIS to that directory It gives the following error

```
 HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
 The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
```

Any Idea what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on the steps you're taking from your question, but it looks like your ultimate goal is to use TeamCity to create a deployable package and publish that to IIS. Your best bet is to do this using WebDeploy and fire it off from a Visual Studio build runner in TeamCity with appropriate parameters. There's a step-by-step guide to doing this in the [You're deploying it wrong](http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/11/you-deploying-it-wrong-teamcity.html) series.